# Integration by substitution and the use of $u = \varphi (x) $

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

The proof of the formula for integration by substitution for definite integrals, using the fundamental theorem of calculus, is very clear to me :

$ \int_{a}^{b}f(\varphi(x)){\varphi}'(x)dx = \int_{a}^{b}{(F\circ \varphi)}'(x)dx \\
\quad = (F\circ \varphi)(b) - (F\circ \varphi)(a) \\\quad= F(\varphi(b)) - (F(\varphi(a))\\\quad=\int_{\varphi(a)}^{\varphi(b)}f(u)du $

But everywhere I've looked at, it is then made use of $ u =\varphi(x) $ for the computations, for example here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_substitution#Example_1.

It is not clear to me at all how rigorous it is to write $ u =\varphi(x) $ and I can't prove it. To me it is simply a variable taking value in the real numbers going from $\varphi(a)$ to $ \varphi(b)$. Can't we simply compute ${\varphi}'(x) $ and go from there, why introduce $u$ ?

Comment: That's because the Riemann integral is only defined with respect to variables, not functions. However, you may be interested in the [Riemann-Stieltjes Integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann%E2%80%93Stieltjes_integral) which does make this notion rigorous.

Comment: You reversed $\phi (a) $ and $\phi (b)$ in your proof